# Remove duplicates line from text file (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove duplicates lines from text file. My codes thus work though but its brings error which i have looked through the codes. Everything works. I used the inbuilt function like the array_unique but the array numbers start from 0 instead of 1. So i'm wondering if anyone could help me . Thanks

````
<?php
hott.txt(content)
vnea@yahoo.com
vnea@yahoo.com
dabrd@gmail.com
vnea@yahoo.com
dabrd@gmail.com
bread@gmail.com
bread@gmail.com
vnea@yahoo.com
dabrd@gmail.com
bread@gmail.com
syeas@hotmail.com
vnea@yahoo.com
vnea@yahoo.com

$contents=file("hott.txt");
$array = [];
foreach ($contents as $k=>$v){

$v = trim($v);
$array[$v]++;
}
print_r($array);


?>

```
````

Comment: If possible please add ex. file to question

Comment: ok sir i will let me see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your file output would be as follows

```
<?php
print_r(file("test.txt"));
?>

Array ( [0] =>vnea@yahoo.com [1] => vnea@yahoo.com [2] => dabrd@gmail.com ...... )
```

Change needed

```
    $contents=file("hott.txt");

    $array = array_map('trim', $contents);

    $array = array_unique($array); //add this line to your code
    
    print_r($array);
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: xrcciosaus@gmail.com in  . It works tho but got that error

Comment: Updated answer ..please check

Comment: it is worth to you..please do upvote

Comment: alright i will, thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

```php
$lines = explode("\n", $lines);
$lines = array_unique($lines);
$lines = implode("\n", $lines);
```

Then write the `$lines` content into your file.